# Printing 3 character of each line in a file in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I was solving one problem from one site, question is as follows:

"Given N lines of input in a file, print the 3rd character from each line as a new line of output. It is guaranteed that each of the n lines of input will have a 3rd character."

So to solve the problem I have written a command

```
while read -r line
do 
      echo ${line:2:1}
done < sample.txt
```

Content in "sample.txt" is :

```
C.B - Cantonment Board/Cantonment
C.M.C â€“ City Municipal Council
C.T â€“ Census Town
E.O â€“ Estate Office
G.P - Gram Panchayat
I.N.A â€“ Industrial Notified Area
I.T.S - Industrial Township
M â€“ Municipality
M.B â€“ Municipal Board
M.C â€“ Municipal Committee
```

I am getting output as follows:

```
B
M
T
O
P
N
T
â
B
C
```

According to the site, the answer should be:

```
B
M
T
O
P
N
T
в
B
C
```

Please not that 3rd last output is "в" and I am getting "â"
I am new to the ascii, uts-8 conversion so not aware if this has any relation .

**What should be change in the code to bring this answer?**

Comment: It looks like you have an encoding problem. Whatever created `sample.txt` is using bytes to represent в that your environment is interpreting as a series of separate characters, the *first* of which is â. That is, the parameter expansion sees only â as the 3rd character, rather than all the bytes together as в.

Comment: As presented in your question, third character of last 3rd line seems a kind of 'a' to me and not like 'b'

Comment: Yes, as I see , I think my answer is correct, however i thought there may be a problem with ascii/utf-8  conversion

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a straightforward `cut` call:

```
$ cut -c3 sample.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, this answer worked. However can you please suggest correction in my answer to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

something with `awk`: Columns are changed to characters using `FS=""`

```
awk -vFS="" '{print $3}' file
```